# WPF ValidationRule Binding is throwing XMLParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have the following ValidationRule class in WPF

```
public class EmptyFieldValidationRule: BaseValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var fieldValue = (string)value;
        if (fieldValue.Trim().Length == 0)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Field Is Empty");
        }
        else
        {
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE - **BaseValidationRule** extends the normal **ValidationRule** class.

This is really just a test validation class because I wanted to start off easier.

I am attempting to bind this to a textbox in my XAML, and it is reading in the BaseValidationRule class fine, it is even giving me it in Intellisense, but when I go to run the program and it hits that part of the application, it tells me an XMLParseException.

I am defining an ErrorMessage property in the XAML, which is inherited in the EmptyFieldValidationRule class from the BaseValidationRule.

The XAML for the ValidationRule Binding looks like the following
[image]

The Error Message I am getting is the following.

**XAMLParseException occured, Could not load file or assembly XXX.ValidationRule, Public KeyToken = null, or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.**

I have made the reference available to the ValidationRule assembly, and the intellisense is reading in the ValidationRule fine in my XAML, is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, make sure you have a XML namespace defined in your XAML document as follows:

```
xmlns:validation="clr-namespace:Some.Assembly.Name.Some.Namespace.Containing.Validations;assembly=Some.Assembly.Name"
```

Where *Some.Assembly.Name.Some.Namespace.Containing.Validations* should be your namespace full name containg `EmptyFieldValidationRule` class, and *Some.Assembly.Name* should be library name for that class.

Answer (score 0):

Is the reference to the validation assembly in the project with the XAML set to "Copy Local = True" ?
If not, this would explain the issue.

Comment: I dont have anything like that, how/where would I specify this?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you have an assembly with the XAML file (X) and another one with the validation code (V). X references V, so looking at the properties of the reference, you should see the 'Copy local' property.

Comment: Does the V assembly depend on other assemblies ? Can you load it in Reflector ?